# Stop Yahoo! from opening in second tab when opening Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, vuze

I recently downloaded Vuze (torrent client), which as well as installing itself, installs a whole bunch of rubbish toolbars (mostly by an outfit called Spigot) and tries to change your default search engine to Yahoo!

In Safari and Firefox, I've managed to change it back but in Chrome, although I've deleted all the addons and restored my default search engine when ever I open up Chrome I get two tabs 1) my default homepage and 2) Yahoo! search page.

Where can I disable this Yahoo! search page? I've looked in the settings but could not find anywhere obvious (I've set back my default search engine to Google and deleted any add-ons) but this still doesn't do it.

My last resort is to do a factory reset of Chrome, which I don't want to do as I have all my settings in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer under *Settings* → *On startup* → *Set pages*.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Had the same issue and finally got rid of it. This is what I did:

1. Control panel > Internet Options > Set home page to www.google.com
2. Control panel > Programs and features > removed applications installed on the same day I updated vuze, there was this app called sprigot
3. In Chrome > Icon top right corner > Settings > Search > "Set which search engine is used when searching from the omnibox". [set to google] > manage search engine > removed any reference to yahoo
4. In Chrome > Icon top right corner > Settings > On Start up > Set Pages > remove yahoo

Not sure if only one of these steps removed yahoo or I needed all of them, but if you follow this yahoo will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, go to Preferences... which will take you to the Settings page. On the Settings page, click on the Extensions link in the column on the far left. If you have the Yahoo Extension enabled, uncheck the enabled box to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the tool bar and search engine by simply going to *Install a Program* in you computer settings and search for 'yahoo'. Then uninstall both the tool bar and the search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Check your extensions (menu>tools>extension). If you have Yahoo search engine installed, disable or delete it. Some of the Yahoo extensions come from applications that you have installed. I got this from an application (not sure what one) that I installed. It can take a while to find.

Maybe in a certain case it can be solved by a different solution. My solution is better, because it prevents the issue from happening again.

Answer (score -1):

I have done this on numerous computers running Chrome:

1. *Settings* → *Appearance* → *Search Engine* → *Search Engine Used in Address Bar*:  Change the dropdown to *Google*
2. *Manage search sngines* → *Default search engines* → *Yahoo!* → *Delete*

(Note that if you go into *Manage search engines* without Step 1 you will only have the option to *Edit* but not *Delete*).

Comment: This removes the Yahoo search engine, but does not solve thr question that was asked

Answer (score -1):

McCafe changes the search on a new tab to secure search.  Go to Chrome settings in top right corner:  You and Google - Search Engine - Change to Google.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I thought I had checked all extensions but after reading these thread answers looked again. There was an extension called "securify for chrome" using my search. Once I disabled that it worked.